# Jquery key up event is not fired on second multi select option in Select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I was facing the problem in select2 plugin for second multiple option,Every time i need to change the option list based on the text user enters

First time when i enter text in multi select field called the keyup event and then calling ajax function to binding with option list here everything works fine

```
$(".select2").on('keyup', function (e) {

    var city = $("#add_city option:selected").text();
    var location = $(".select2-search__field").val();

    var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyCNHGRJsM3uwGUm5gYLGsVrPNyRdeWgYDY&components=country:in&input='+ city +''+ location +'';
    var data ={"url":url};
    console.log(url);
    //return false;
     $.ajax({
    url: 'webservice.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data:JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (response) {
        //alert(response);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        for(var i in response)
        {
            $("#add_area").append("<option value=\"" + response[i] + "\">" + response[i] + "</option>");
        }}
    ,error: function(xhr, status, error) {}});
```

but second time when i try to enter text in field keyup event is not fired and failed to call ajax on that

I have seen solution in the document we need to refresh the option list for that when user select option then i am executing following line

```
$('#add_area').select2('destroy').empty().select2({data: [{id: 1, text: 'new text'}]});
```

above line cleared the options but keyup event is not fired.

Please help how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: You are refreshing list and hence creating new element so the previously bind keyup event handler won't work 
Replace below code

```
$(".select2").on('keyup', function (e) {
```

with

```
$(document).on('keyup',".select2", function (e) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply can i refresh the options with out removing the selected option ?

Comment: You can but for that you need write logic where you have save selected option in some variable and then after refreshing the select option you need to read the variable to select previously selected options